# Using Fluent Validation, in Web API project: derived classes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation

I am trying to implement a custom validation using "FluentValidation" into a WebApi project.

So, in my action method(POST) from Controller, I use the base class (Person) as parameter:

```
[Route("persons/compute")] public HttpResponseMessage Compute(Person person)  { ... }
```

From nuget I have installed "FluentValidation and FluentValidation.WebApi" packages.

I have the follwing code:

```
[Serializable]   
public class Person
{        
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string CNP { get; set; } //unique identifier
}

 [Serializable]
 [Validator(typeof(StudentValidator))]
 public class Student : Person
 {
    public string CollegeName { get; set; }      
 }
```

Validator classes are:

```
 public abstract class PersonValidator<T>: AbstractValidator<T> where T : Person
        {
            protected abstract PersonClassType PersonClassType { get; }
            public PersonValidator()
            {
                Custom(p => {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.CNP))
                    {
                        return new ValidationFailure("Insured.UniqueIdentifier", "CNP/CUI obligatoriu!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        decimal cnp;
                        bool isCNP = (p.CNP.Length == 13 && decimal.TryParse(p.CNP, out cnp));
                        if (!isCNP)
                        {
                            return new ValidationFailure("Insured.UniqueIdentifier", "CNP invalid!");
                        }
                    }
                    return null;
                });
            }
        }
```

The Validator for derived class is:

```
public class StudentValidator : PersonValidator<Student>
    {
        public StudentValidator ()
        {
            Custom(p => {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.CollegeName))
                {
                    return new ValidationFailure("ekfjekfj", "College Name mandatory!");
                }            

                return null;
            });
        }

        protected override PersonClassType PersonClassType
        {
            get
            {
                return PersonClassType.Student;
            }
        }
    }

 [DataContract]
    public enum PersonClassType
    {
        None = int.MinValue,
        Student = 1,
        Employee = 2
    }
```

In Global.asax.cs, in Application_Start(), I added:

```
 FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

**What I need?: In action method, in controller, using the parameter of type base class(Person) to make the validation for children/derived(ex:Student, Employee, etc) classess  which are received from body (POST). So, it need to know to switch to the right validator.** 
I suppose that this issue could be resolved using "Factory" or "DepencyInjection", but I do not know how.
I hope make myself clear. 
My appollogize, but my English it's not perfect.

I would appreciate an explicit solution because I have tried to implement with Factory but I did not managed. I could send the zip file with my code, if it is needed.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3):

To handle this, I created the following class:

```
public class ValidatorBase<TBase> : AbstractValidator<TBase>
{
    public void MapDerivedValidator<TType, TValidatorType>()
        where TValidatorType : IEnumerable<IValidationRule>, IValidator<TType>, new()
        where TType: TBase
    {
        When(t => t.GetType() == typeof(TType), () => AddDerivedRules<TValidatorType>());
    }

    private void AddDerivedRules<T>()
        where T : IEnumerable<IValidationRule>, new()
    {
        IEnumerable<IValidationRule> validator = new T();
        foreach (var rule in validator)
        {
            this.AddRule(rule);
        }
    }
}
```

To use it, change your Person validator to inherit from ValidatorBase (replace `AbstractValidator<Person>` with `ValidatorBase<Person>`).

Now, when you're setting up the rules for Person validation, add the following line:

`MapDerivedValidator<Student, StudentValidator>`

StudentValidator can simply inherit from `AbstractValidator<Student>` as it normally would.

---

What we're doing here is basically *conditionally including* in the base class's validator (PersonValidator) the rules from the derived class' validator (StudentValidator) when the type being validated matches.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Now when I try to implement in real code, I do not understand why the validator does not work. What am I missing !? The sample application works fine and it is the same structure ..

Answer (score 1):

To be useful for others, the update code, based on Jon solution, would be:

```
 [Route("persons/compute")]
        public HttpResponseMessage Compute([FromBody]Person person)
        {...}
```

In Global.asax.cs :

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

            JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
            serializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;
            serializerSettings.TypeNameAssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple;
            serializerSettings.FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal;

            FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

        }
```

Adding class: ValidatorBase (see above in Jon answer)

Update PersonValidator.cs as follow:

```
   public PersonValidator()
            {
                MapDerivedValidator<Student, StudentValidator>();
                MapDerivedValidator<Employee, EmployeeValidator>();
                //.... other derived classes
    ...
    }



public class StudentValidator : ValidatorBase<Student>
    { ...}
```

Thanks Jon!